# Upload file to server Issue in C# Asp.net

Tags: c#-4.0, upload, ftp

i want to upload a file to server and here is my code which do not work

```
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.com/myfolder");
         request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("aaa", "aaa");

        // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("c://a.txt");
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

        response.Close();
```

i can access ftp through filezilla with these credentials.nothing is uploading in this case.
Now when i want to upload to another folder inside like
ftp://mysite.com/myfolder/anotherfolder
if give me error that file or folder not availble etc etc
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is presenting that folder doesn't exist either on sever or local.
Please make sure that folder which is you are trying to access already exist on server and client.

Comment: i am writing this comment for others as this point saved alot of my time...the isue was in FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp://ftp.mysite.com/t/a.txt)...also we do not need to have a.txt in the folder as source